# Multiple OAuth redirect URIs for Dropbox Datastore API?

Tags: oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

I wonder how the OAuth 2.0 redirect URI works, the App console over at Dropbox allows me to add multiple URL;s so what I really wonder is do I need to add every URL that needs access to the API?

A small exemple:

At the page index.html the user is prompt to connect to Dropbox, when connected the user is sent to app.html there the app it self is. What should then be the redirect URI, the index.html, the app.html or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* have to register each URL from which you access the API, just the one that the user is redirected back to after authorizing the app. Generally you'll only have one of these in production, but you might also use a localhost URL during development.